# C++ GetAsyncKeyState alternative

Tags: c++, keyboard

I was using Windows.h library's GetAsyncKeyState function to define which key was pushed on the keyboard . Here is the program which returns the int value of the pushed key for example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    char i;
    for(i=8;i<190;i++){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i)== -32767){
            cout<<int (i)<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But now I am trying to make an openGl very simple game and this function appeared to be very slow for that . Is there a function which will not need a for cycle 180 times and an if statement .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make a opengl game, so you're probably going to use GLFW. If that's the case then you can get away with using `glfwGetKey()` as such:

```
if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS) {...}
if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS) {...}
```

That method is nicely explained in [tutorial 6](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/) from [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org). But you should probably start from the first tutorial of [beginners tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/) and later [intermediate tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/).

If you're going to make the win32 window by yourself you can listen for the [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages and get the [virtual key code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from wparam. After a minute of googling I found you these two sites for examples [here](http://www.zeuscmd.com/tutorials/win32/07-KeyboardInput.php) and [here](http://xoax.net/cpp/crs/win32/lessons/Lesson10/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `PeekMessage` and `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`. It's quite simple to register your own windows procedure (WNDPROC) to process input messages from windows.

```
MSG msg;
while(PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ))
{
    TranslateMessage( &msg );
    DispatchMessage( &msg );
}
```

The `DispatchMessage` function calls your registered procedure. See: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384843.aspx) for more info.